# can't able to update custom property aspects in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I’m having problem while adding the aspect to the required folders in Alfresco Share (**Alfresco 4.2**). When I click Manage Aspects, select the desired aspect then Save, a message pops up saying “**Could not update aspects**”.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you..

**share-config-custom.xml**

```
     <aspects>
     <!-- Aspects that a user can see -->
     <visible>
        <aspect name="cm:generalclassifiable" />
        <aspect name="cm:complianceable" />
        <aspect name="cm:dublincore" />
        <aspect name="cm:effectivity" />
        <aspect name="cm:summarizable" />
        <aspect name="cm:versionable" />
        <aspect name="cm:templatable" />
        <aspect name="cm:emailed" />
        <aspect name="emailserver:aliasable" />
        <aspect name="cm:taggable" />
        <aspect name="app:inlineeditable" />
        <aspect name="gd:googleEditable" />
        <aspect name="cm:geographic" />
        <aspect name="exif:exif" />
        <aspect name="audio:audio" />
        <aspect name="cm:indexControl" />
        <aspect name="dp:restrictable" />
        <aspect name="kb:referencable" />
     </visible>

     <!-- Aspects that a user can add. Same as "visible" if left empty -->
     <addable>
     </addable>

     <!-- Aspects that a user can remove. Same as "visible" if left empty -->
     <removeable>
     </removeable>
    </aspects>
```

**custom-slingshot-application-context.xml.sample**

```
 <bean id="webscripts.kb.resources" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
  <property name="resourceBundles">
     <list>
        <value>alfresco.messages.knowledgebase</value>
     </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

**web-client-config-custom.xml.sample**

```
<config evaluator="aspect-name" condition="kb:referencable">
     <property-sheet>
         <show-property name="kb:documentRef"/>
    </property-sheet>
</config>
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Action Wizards">
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="my:docProps" />
    </aspects>
</config>
```

**kb-model.xml**

```
<aspects>
  <!-- Definition of new Content Aspect: Knowledge Base Document -->
  <aspect name="kb:referencable">
     <title>Knowledge Base Referencable</title>
     <properties>
        <property name="kb:documentRef">
           <type>d:text</type>
        </property>
     </properties>
  </aspect>
 </aspects>
```

**kb-model-context.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans>
<!-- Registration of new models -->
<bean id="extension.kb.dictionaryBootstrap" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
    <property name="models">
        <list>
            <value>alfresco/extension/kb-model.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="extension.kb.resourceBundle"   class="org.alfresco.i18n.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
   <property name="resourceBundles">
      <list>
         <value>alfresco.messages.knowledgebase</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: are you adding custom aspects?If yes than the name in share-config and the model file of alfresco is not same

Comment: @Krutik Jayswal:yes.iam trying to add a new custom aspects. But it show same name in share-config and the model file.

Comment: have you created context file and injected that model?Please give me detail regarding how you are creating aspect.

Comment: iam create as this blog:http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2010/02/25/adding-custom-aspect-support-in-alfresco-share/

Comment: I am sure you are missing something from that blog.Upload your files than only I will able to find out problem

Comment: now its save in web view. but when i try to insert document in java code it show an error.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException: Type 'kb:referencable' is unknown!
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:467)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67887/discussion-between-arun-m-r-nair-and-krutik-jayswal).

Answer (score 2):

For creating aspect in Alfresco There are three main files which deals with aspects.

1.Model File In which you are defining aspect.

2.Context File(From which you are injecting model file)

3.Adding aspect for visibility in share-config-custom(Or web-client config if alfresco version is <5.0b)

Example of all above are as below.

**Model File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model name="model1:ExtensionModel"  xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" >
    <description>Extension model</description>
    <author>Krutik Jayswal</author>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <imports>
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
    </imports>
    <namespaces>
        <namespace uri="http://www.model.com/model/model/1.0" prefix="m1"/>
    </namespaces>
    <data-types/>
    <constraints/>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="m1:metadata1">
            <title>Meta data 1</title>
            <properties>
                <property name="m1:Solution">
                    <title>Solution</title>
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <index enabled="true">
                        <atomic>true</atomic>
                        <stored>true</stored>
                        <tokenised>TRUE</tokenised>
                    </index>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </aspect>
    </aspects>
</model>
```

**Context File**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
    <beans>

        <!-- Registration of new models -->    
        <bean id="extension.dictionaryBootstrap" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
            <property name="models">
                <list>
                    <value>alfresco/extension/extCustomModel.xml</value><!--This is path till model file.alfresco directory will be inside tomcat/shared classes/**alfresco**-->
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

**Share-Config-Custom**

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">

         <aspects>

             <visible>

                <aspect name="m1:metadata1" />

             </visible>

         </aspects>

   </config>
```

Comment: Could you share exact file name's like what is model or context file?